# sed Switch Comment

Tags: awk, sed

I have the following in a file

```
$db['db'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    // 'username' => 'user',
    'password' => 'removed',
    'database' => 'one'
    // 'database' => 'two'
);
```

I need to comment the first and uncomment the second 'username' and 'database'. I'm trying to swap them with sed by replacing and then adding to no success.

I need the following overwritten to the original file

```
$db['db'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    // 'username' => 'root',
    'username' => 'user',
    'password' => 'removed',
    // 'database' => 'one'
    'database' => 'two'
);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using GNU awk for the 3rd arg to `match()` and "inplace" editing:

```
$ awk -i inplace '
match($0,/(.*)(\047username\047[[:space:]]*=>.*)/,a) {
    $0 = ( sub("//[[:space:]]*","",a[1]) ? a[1] : a[1] "// " ) a[2]
}
1' file
```

```
$ cat file
$db['db'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    // 'username' => 'root',
    'username' => 'user',
    'password' => 'removed',
    'database' => 'db'
);
```

Here it is as a shell function as requested:

```
swap() {
    awk -i inplace -v tgt="$1" '
        match($0,"(.*)(\047" tgt "\047[[:space:]]*=>.*)",a) {
            $0 = ( sub("//[[:space:]]*","",a[1]) ? a[1] : a[1] "// " ) a[2]
        }
    1' "$2"
}
```

```
$ swap username file
```

```
$ cat file
$db['db'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    // 'username' => 'root',
    'username' => 'user',
    'password' => 'removed',
    'database' => 'db'
    // 'database' => 'db'
);
```

```
$ swap database file
```

```
$ cat file
$db['db'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    // 'username' => 'root',
    'username' => 'user',
    'password' => 'removed',
    // 'database' => 'db'
    'database' => 'db'
);
```

Comment: You get style points for handling the single-quotes too. (shouldn't have missed that `:)`

Comment: Is it possible to wrap it in a function? I need to do the same switch for 'database'.

Comment: Yes, that's simple. Please [edit] your question to add those requirements, though, as [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) are strongly discouraged.

Comment: I revised the question. No more edits needed once it's wrapped so I can use it against 'username' and 'database'.

Answer (score 3):

It's probably a lot easier to do with `awk` because `sed` can't count. With `awk` you can do:

```
awk '$1~/username/{if (seen++) sub("^//",""); else sub(/^/,"//") }1' file
```

Above, `awk` uses a single rule and checks if `"username"` is present in the first field. If so, it checks if the variable `seen` is set, (meaning `"username"` has already been seen) if it has been seen, is uses `sub` to remove the leading `"//"`. If this is the first time `"username"` is seen (the `else` part), it adds `"//"` at the beginning of the line. The `'1'` at the end is just shorthand for print each record.

**Example Use/Output**

With your input in `file`, you would have:

```
$ awk '$1~/username/{if (seen++) sub("^//",""); else sub(/^/,"//") }1' file
//'username' => 'one',
'username' => 'two',
```

Let me know if you have further questions.

**Update Per-Edit**

With whitespace before and between the comment and start of code, your field numbering changes. You can still handle that with `awk`, but you need to key on the complete record and not simply the first field, e.g.

```
awk '$0~"\047username\047"{if (seen++) sub("// ",""); else sub(/^[[:blank:]]*/,"    // ") }1' file
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ awk '$0~"\047username\047"{if (seen++) sub("// ",""); else sub(/^[[:blank:]]*/,"    // ") }1' file
$db['db'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    // 'username' => 'root',
    'username' => 'user',
    'password' => 'removed',
    'database' => 'db'
);
```

Updated to discriminate `"'username'"` better.

Comment: I tried it, didn't work. I'm on a Mac. It just outputs the file text into terminal.

Comment: @whisky - which version did you try. Sorry for updating it, but Ed kept making it better `:)`

Comment: @whisky that command will work just fine with any awk in any shell on every Unix box. If it doesn't work for you then you copy/pasted it wrong or your real input doesn't look like the input you posted in your question. Actually are you saying "it didn't work" because a) it didn't change the text and printed an exact copy of the input file to the terminal or b) it output the modified text to the terminal instead of updating the input file?

Comment: You're right, it isn't writing to the file. It just outputs.

Comment: The fields also have some spacing in the front and the output doesn't look like it works with the spacing in front. The spacing is ' '.

Comment: In that case use `{if (seen++) sub(/^[[:blank:]]*\/\//,"");` to remove the leading `//` skipping zero or more occurrences of any blank character.

Comment: Almost all Unix tools write their output to stdout. To modify the input file you usually need to do do `tmp=$(mktemp); tool 'script' file > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" file` but some tools have options to create/move that temp file for you behind the scenes, e.g. with GNU awk you can do `awk -i inplace 'script' file`. By the way you're using sed I can tell it's GNU sed (the default MacOS sed requires a file name after `-i`) so you must have GNU awk available too the same way you installed GNU sed.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the same spacing in your example as you have in your real data. Also, add the expected output, don't just show the sample input.

Comment: @David `sub(/^[[:blank:]]*\/\//,"")` could be written `sub("^[[:blank:]]*//","")` for slighlty improved clarity but more importantly the OP talking about "spacing" could mean the input looks like `// 'username'...` so then $1 would be just `//` instead of `//'username'`. We'll see what they show us in their question.

Comment: That's good,  I was a little cautious on how far I could take the regex-in-a-string and was unclear on whether the character class would expand double quoted. Thank you again.

Comment: Revised the question

Comment: @whisky that looks like some type of .json config and this is a perfect example of why it is dangerous to handle json with shell utilities. If that is a fixed format it is still doable, but we will have to assume a fixed width of whitespace before the text. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @David The difference between `/regexp/` (a regexp constant) and `"regexp"` (a dynamic regexp) is that the latter has to be parsed twice, first to convert it to a regexp and then to use it as a regexp, and so backslash escapes need to be doubled in up to account for those 2 phases of parsing. Other than that, the former needs `/`s escaped while the latter needs `"`s escaped (since they're the respective delimiters) and that's it.

Comment: It's a fixed format with fixed width of whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking for a sed option, here is one.

```
$ cat test.sed
s#^'u\(.*\)one#//'u\1one#
s#^//'u\(.*\)two#'u\1two#

$ cat test.txt
'username' => 'one',
//'username' => 'two',

$ sed -i -f test.sed test.txt

$ cat test.txt
//'username' => 'one',
'username' => 'two',
```

Comment: I could be wrong but it seems like the OP wants to do the replacement based on the tag name (e.g. `username`), not it's value (e.g. `one`).

Comment: @EdMorton its a regex so it picks up everything between u to one. Of course OP has since changed the text so it may seem a bit confusing but the idea remains the same.

Comment: I understand that but I don't think the OP wants to change `'underwater' => 'one'` as that script would change, and that wouldn't change `'username' => 'root'` which the OP does want to change. I THINK they just want to change occurrences of `'username' =>` (and now also `'database' =>`).

Comment: Ah, got it Ed. In that case this will not work. I can delete this solution if you like.

Comment: Doesn't matter to me, just thought you'd want to know. Whatever you do with that info is fine with me.

Answer (score 0):

If `ed` is available/acceptable.

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

ed -s file.txt <<-'EOF'
  g|^\([[:blank:]]*\)\('username' => 'root',\)$|s||\1// \2|\
  +1s|^\([^/]*\) // \('username' => 'user',\)$|\1 \2|
  g|^\([[:blank:]]*\)\('database' => 'one'\)$|s||\1// \2|\
  +1s|^\([^/]*\) // \('database' => 'two'\)$|\1 \2|
  ,p
  Q
EOF
```

---

- Remove the `,p` to silence the output to `stdout`
- Chane `Q` to `w` if *in-place* editing is needed.